# Topological space $(X, \tau)$ is not path connected given conditions on a quotient space of $(X, \tau)$.

Tags: general-topology

While studying topology I came across the following question.

> Let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological space and let $q : X \to Y$ be a
> surjective function. Consider the quotient topology on $Y$ induced by
> the function $q$.    Assume that $Y$ is path connected and that each
> set $q^{-1}(y)$ is path connected. Is it true that $(X, \tau)$ is path
> connected?

---

**My attempt and work on this question (not mandatory reading):**

My idea is that the above statement does not need to hold. I was able to show that the statement holds when we use 'connected' in stead of 'path connected'. However since connectedness does not imply path connectedness this result doesn't seem very helpful.

I then tried to construct topological spaces $X$ and $Y$ which form a counterexample. I tried to consider for the space $X$ the topologist's sine curve. However I could not find a suitable function $q$ to disprove the result. Any tips on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated.

My background knowledge consists of basic topological concepts.

Comment: Are $Y$ and $Z$ the same?

Comment: Oh yes I will edit it, I confused the notations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is wrong. Consider the closed topologist's sine curve $S = \{(x,\sin(1/x) \mid x \in (0,1]\} \cup \{0\} \times [-1,1]$. This a connected, but not path connected subspace of $\mathbb R^2$. The map $p : S \to [0,1], p(x,y) = x$, has the property that all fibers $p^{-1}(x)$ are path connected.